# Show only specific number of question from randomize array

Tags: php

the randomize function is working fine with shuffle array of question. how can we pick specific amount  by 'N' numbers to remove from the array each time when randomize works.
Means if we wish to show 20% or 20 questions from a list of 100 questions each time in randomize mode

```
public function random_questions( $quiz_questions, $quiz_id ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $quiz_id, '_lp_random_mode', true ) == 'yes' ) {
        // get user meta random quiz
        $random_quiz = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'random_quiz', true );
        if ( is_admin() || empty( $random_quiz ) || empty( $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] ) ) {
            return $quiz_questions;
        }
        $questions = array();
        if ( array_key_exists( $quiz_id, $random_quiz ) && sizeof( $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] ) == sizeof( $quiz_questions ) ) {
            foreach ( $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] as $question_id ) {
                if ( $question_id ) {
                    $questions[ $question_id ] = $question_id;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $question_ids = array_keys( $quiz_questions );
            shuffle( $question_ids );
            $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] = $question_ids;
            $questions               = array();
            foreach ( $question_ids as $id ) {
                $questions[ $id ] = $quiz_questions[ $id ];
            }
        }
        return $questions;
    }
    return $quiz_questions;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `array_rand()` function. You specify an array and the number of items you want, and it selects that many random elements. Or you could use `shuffle()` and then take the first N elements.

Comment: shuffle() is what i am using to randomize the questions array and it is working quite good..i only need specific number of items each time randomly .

Comment: After shuffling: `$selected_questions = array_slice($question_ids, 0, $N)`

Comment: where to save those $N numbers in meta as input variable

Comment: You can save it anywhere you want, just give it a name for the meta table.

Comment: shuffle( $question_ids );
$selected_questions = array_slice($question_ids, 0, $N)
$random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] = $selected_questions;

right?

Comment: what does 0 do in array_slice.

Comment: It's the starting index of the slice.

Comment: Can't you read documentation?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Comment: i will check this if this working or not. thanks btw

Comment: Not working i did explored that due to array type of keys it is not working. Can you look the structure of it again @barmar

Comment: May be i should true paramter in array slice and above then the ==sizeof should be removed because array is changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random selection of array keys, instead of using all the keys with `array_keys()`. Then it's not necessary to shuffle the array.

```
        $question_ids = array_rand( $quiz_questions , 20);
        $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] = $question_ids;
        $questions               = array();
        foreach ( $question_ids as $id ) {
            $questions[ $id ] = $quiz_questions[ $id ];
        }
```

Comment: its is getting me the first 20 array elements out of 100 in a shuffle form. but how can we select any 20 array elements out of 100. not first not last. but any

Comment: No it isn't. `array_rand()` picks 20 randomly, not the first 20.

Comment: yeah i notice it sometimes picks any of the random 20. but not everytime just stick to it first time. at the code runs it randomly picks 20 from 100 then give this again and again.. the shuffle function gives everytime a new set of order each time the loop runs

Comment: Are you calling `srand()` before each time you call this function? Don't do that.

Comment: now i am not calling srand() . the problem is i have quiz module.. previously the *shuffle function only* was able to get me new set of order shuffled each time. when i click retake everytime like 1st time a,b,c - 2nd time b,c,a . while array_rand($array,2) gives 1st time b,c - 2nd time is again gives me b,c

Comment: See https://ideone.com/moQRxG it shows that `array_rand()` returns a different array every time it's called.